# iPython bokeh import error Row and SizingMode

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, python-import, bokeh

I followed this notebook to try bokeh with iPyhton Notebook: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.3/examples/howto/notebook_comms/Basic%20Usage.ipynb

I dont know how to interpret and fix those errors:

***error 1:***

```
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()
```

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         3 
>         4 from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
>   ----> 5 from bokeh.layouts import row
>         6 from bokeh.plotting import figure
>         7 output_notebook()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/layouts.py in ()
>         8 from **future** import absolute_import
>         9 
>   ---> 10 from .core.enums import Location, SizingMode
>        11 from .models.tools import ToolbarBox
>        12 from .models.plots import Plot
>
> ImportError: cannot import name SizingMode

***error 2:***

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()
```

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         6 
>         7 from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
>   ----> 8 from bokeh.plotting import figure
>         9 output_notebook()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/plotting/**init**.py in
>   ()
>         3 
>         4 from ..models import ColumnDataSource; ColumnDataSource
>   ----> 5 from ..models.layouts import Row, Column; Row, Column
>         6 
>         7 from ..io import curdoc; curdoc
>
> ImportError: cannot import name Row

bokeh :  0.12.3

tornado: 4.4.2

python: 2.7

Comment: You have an installation problem, or the you have different environments mixed up (i.e. the env with notebook has a different version of bokeh). What is the value of `bokeh.__version__` while inside the notebook?

Comment: restarting the notebook server solved the version conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that the iPython notebook kernel was out of sync. restarting the notebook server was the solution